# Unable to click Elementor Elements with Selenium

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

For a while now I've been trying to automate Elementor with Selenium. It seems impossible to find the elements since there is no option to right click and inspect, and even after finding the xpath\classname\css Selectors with some tools it still didnt click the element.
Been trying to select simple elements like in the example below:
https://prnt.sc/P1Kz2cJbijV3
Maybe its because its not a button. altho clicking it should open the tab on the right.'
Any ideas? :)

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: _finding the xpath\classname\css Selectors with some tools it still didnt click the element_: Update the question with text based relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Elementor is actually an editor. I don't think you can right click on that. Try opening up the console using F9 and you will see the HTML code. I believe you can check the HTML code and figure out where the element might be and when you click a particular div or or something you want to get the xpath it would show point to you at the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I tried xpath finder and the html code, sometimes i get element unclickable and sometimes it doesnt even find it.

Comment: Even if I could browse through the Elementor navigation tab would be helpful.
Any ideas?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/PQO5EIJCadeh
Screenshot of the element I'd like to click